# jquery iu disableSelection() and enableSelection()

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a div called desktop and I disableSelection() on this. Inside this div I create Dialogs as user input forms. The problem is that when I disableSelection I have problems with input elements on the form. I tried to enableSelection() for input elements but it's not working. Any ideas, suggestions?

Thank you in advance!!!

**Edit**
I moved a bit further removing dialogs form desktop making input elements to work. The problem now is that start dragging from inside the Dialog labels are getting selected.
I can live with that but I would like a nice solution!

[image]

Comment: `disableSelection` and `enableSelection` are pretty much undocumented. I wouldn't be surprised if you see issues...

Comment: You are right but what else I could use?

Comment: I am not sure, however looking at the source code might help: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.core.js#L110

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Since I couldn't find anything I checked the code but it couldn't help me at all!

Comment: Why are you using ```disableSelection``` and ```enableSelection``` in the first place?  Why not just set the ```readOnly``` or ```disabled``` attribute on the form field?